# Showing that for a metric space $(X,d)$, $|d(x,z) - d(y,z)| \leq d(x,y)$.

Tags: general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I am currently working through a proof that is given in my textbook (for a course in metric spaces) for the following question:

> if $(X,d)$ is a metric space, show that $|d(x,z) - d(y,z)| \leq d(x,y)$ $\forall x,y,z \in X$.

**Proof**:

$(1)$ by the triangle inequality we have that $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ and therefore

$(2)$ $d(x,z) - d(y,z) \leq d(x,y)$.

$(3)$ Again, by the triangle inequality: $d(y,z) \leq d(y,x) + d(x,z)$, and therefore by symmetry:

$(4)$ $-(d(x,z) - d(y,z)) \leq d(y,x) = d(x,y)$.

$(5)$ *combining* $(2)$ and $(4)$ we get $|d(x,z) - d(y,z)| \leq d(x,y)$.

---

**My questions**:

$i)$ In $(1)$, how do we know by the triangle inequality that $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$? an similarly for $(3)$, how do we know that $d(y,z) \leq d(y,x) + d(x,z)$?

$ii)$ in $(5)$, what does the author mean by "combining" the inequalities in $(2)$ and $(4)$ to yield the final result? I feel this is a bit vague and can't seem to understand what he means by "combine".

The reason for my questions is I want to be able to write a thorough proof for this, but I wanted to clear some things up.

Comment: The triangle inequality is part of the defining properties of the metric $d$. "combine" means (2) and (4) together imply (5); note that in general if $a\leq b$ and $-a\leq b$, then it follows that $|a| \leq b$ (prove this simpler statement first)

Comment: In $(1)$ and $(3)$ that is simply what the triangle inequality, which by definition every metric satisfies, **says**.

Comment: For (5) $-a\leq b $  and $a\leq b$ if only if $|a|\leq b$.

Comment: $(2)$ and $(4)$ have the form $a-b\le c$ and $-(a-b)\le c$. Now $|a-b|$ is equal either to $a-b$ or to $-(a-b)$, so whichever of those it happens to be, $|a-b|\le c$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - What is the significance of step $(3)$? I feel like it is not needed since taking the negative of the inequality of $(2)$ gives $(4)$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Taking the negative of $(2)$ does **not** give $(4)$: taking the negative of an inequality reverses its direction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Whoops! Of course, I see why $(3)$ is needed now. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @TaylorRendon: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i) The definition of the triangle inequality is that for all $x, y, z$, we have $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$. By the definition of a metric, the triangle inequality must be true.

ii) We have in general $|a| = \sup(a, -a)$. In other words, $|a|$ is the smallest value $w$ s.t. $w \geq a$ and $w \geq -a$. Let $a = d(x, z) - d(y, x)$. Then we have shown that $d(x, y) \geq a$ and $d(x, y) \geq -a$. Therefore, $d(x, y) \geq |a|$.

Comment: Great explanation.